# Foundation use offset only for medium screen

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation, offset

I have a little problem with Foundation 5 and the grid.

I try to apply an offset only for medium screen, but it seem to apply on large and small screen too.
There is the code :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 medium-offset-1 medium-6 columns">
      <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 medium-5 columns">
    <div class="right"><p>Hello world 2</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `medium-offset-1` is only for medium but the large screen have also the offset...

Why is that ?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please?

Comment: the view of Jsfiddle is too small to provide a view for large screen... http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/266/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly use `large-offset-0`

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="large-6 medium-offset-1 large-offset-0 medium-6 columns">

      <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 medium-5 columns">
    <div class="right"><p>Hello world 2</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: see my edit i have large-6 and larg-6 so there is a full row.